# Video chat app with desktop sharing

Tags: skype, google-hangouts

What is the state-of-the-art in Linux video chat featuring desktop sharing?

I do not need group chat. I only need one-to-one chat where we can see each other desktops'. If possible we would also like to interact with the other person's desktop.

I will be using Ubuntu and the other person uses some version of Windows. The desktop sharing needs to be good enough so that we can read normal fonts from each other's computers.

- **Skype** has a 4.x release in Linux (but no 5.x) and people [are having problems when the other person is using Windows](https://community.skype.com/t5/Linux-archive/screen-sharing-on-Skype-4-3-0-37-atrocious-image-quality/td-p/3285254)
- **Hangouts**.google.com seems simple enough and [seems to the job, according to Google](https://support.google.com/plus/answer/1660627?hl=en)

Neither option allows interacting with the other person's desktop, do they? What else is there?

Answer (score 2):

What about [Teamviewer](https://www.teamviewer.com/en/)? It has a free version for Linux and Windows, which has basic functions such as allowing interaction with one another’s desktop, and you may make voice calls.

Comment: Newer versions of TeamViewer also have support for video calls!